# Displaying a users post on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display a users "post" in a table view on iOS. When a users writes a post and hits the post button in my app, the post is saved to my firebase real time data base but it is not displaying in the tableview on the viewcontroller on which the code is written in. I'm not sure if its my code or something to do with firebase not responding and showing the data. Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeViewController:UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableView:UITableView!

    var posts = [Post] ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.observePosts()

        tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)

        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")
        view.addSubview(tableView)


        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func observePosts() {
        let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

        postsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in


            print(snapshot.value)

            var tempPosts = [Post]()


            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                    let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                    let author = dict["author"] as? [String:Any],
                    let uid = author["uid"] as? String,
                    let fullname = author["username"] as? String,
                    let photoURL = author["photoURL"] as? String,
                    let url = URL (string:photoURL),
                    let text = dict["text"] as? String,
                    let timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? Double {

                    let userProfile = UserProfile(uid: uid, fullname: fullname, photoURL: url)
                    let post = Post(id: childSnapshot.key, author: userProfile, text: text, timestamp: timestamp)
                    tempPosts.append(post)
            }
        }
            self.posts = tempPosts
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

Also is this helps, here are my database rules:

```
{
 "rules" :{
        "posts" : {
            ".write" : true, 
            ".read": true

       },
        "users" : {
            ".write" : true,  
            ".read" : true
       }
     } 
  }
```

**Here are examples of my `PostTableViewCell`, `Post` Class and my `PostTableViewCell.xib`:** [Post Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtGcF.png) [PostTableViewCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzozX.png) [PostTableViewCell.xib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnYDe.png)

**Also This is what it my code looks like when entering plain data.**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeViewController:UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableView:UITableView!

    var posts = ["This is a text"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)

        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")
        view.addSubview(tableView)


        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.reloadData()

    }


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

**And this is what it looks like when I run my app.** [TableView Loadout With Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzteU.png)

Comment: You need to do some debug. Under the line `self.posts = tempPosts`, try to : `print("[TEST] \(self.posts.count)")`. You will know if Firebase is returning data.

Comment: Also, no need to self.tableView.reloadData() twice (once in viewDidLoad, and once in your observe method).

Comment: What are you doing inside of the `cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])` method? Is it possible that you are simply never writing the information to the cell UI? I would try to log if a valid post is found at that point.

Comment: @Arthur I went a head and wrote that line of code under the self.posts = tempPosts and nothing displayed.

Comment: @allenhinson214 It seems you are not entering inside the Firebase observer. Sorry I never used Firebase database, I don't know how it works. Did you check if your Firebase Database contains data inside ?

Comment: @Arthur The "post" data is storing in Firebase database correctly under the "posts" node. So all the data is saving in there, it is just not relaying back to the tableview where it needs to display, here is an image that shows the data: https://ibb.co/Tk8tv8t

Comment: @allenhinson214 Could you try this : `let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("mixed-with-music-28704/posts")`

Comment: @Arthur I tried using that and it didn't display any "posts" on the application side, it saved the data in firebase under the "posts" node. Still not understanding why it is not displaying correctly.

Comment: @allenhinson214 First, I think you should keep a `print("test")` or a breakpoints inside your observer block to know when you succeed to receive data. You may have an other problem with the data display.

`let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")`

I'm not sure about this line. You have to go across all your tree. And by looking at your screenshot, it seems to start with `mixed-with-music-28704` and then with that child you will be able to access to `posts`

Comment: Two questions. 1) Did you verify that your tableView datasource `self.posts` is in fact being populated from Firebase? I would wire up a button for testing that you can click which will print the contents of that array to the console. 2) replace `cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])` with `cell.textLabel!.text = "Hello, World"` and see if your tableView displays anything. I suspect your tableView is not being entirely constructed in code.

Comment: @Jay I’m not exactly sure what you mean for number 1 but when I do what you suggest on number 2 nothing displays. When I originally had it set up to test if the table view was working properly “var posts = [Post]( )” was originally set up as “var posts = [  (id: “1”, author: “Allen”, text: “What’s going on”) ]” and that would display properly

Comment: Hmm. 1) means you should verify the datasource array is being populated with data from firebase... Not sure how to better ask that.. if the firebase isn't returning any data then the array will contain nothing and nothing will show in your tableView.

Comment: @Jay to be honest with you I'm new to firebase database and coding with swift so trying to figure out whether firebase is returning anything is kinda hard for me to figure out. Like I said, I know everything is saving correctly in side of firebase, I'm just not sure why this code isn't displaying that data correctly

Comment: It's pretty simple to figure that one out; right after this `self.posts = tempPosts` add a `self.posts.forEach { print($0) }` and see if it prints your data. If it does then you know your dataSource is populated and the issue probably lies with how your tableView is set up. Perhaps you didn't add the 'postCell' identifier to the tableView tableCellView prototype, or maybe PostTableViewCell has an issue. First though, ensure you've got good data and then you can troubleshoot your tableView.

Comment: @Jay would the information show up in the debug area? I inputed this line of code and I don't see anything showing the data from my firebase database.

Comment: @Jay Not sure if this is what we are looking for but when I got to my debugger I see this line pop up `2019-12-05 13:01:50.461539-0600 new app 3[49543:5045404] 6.12.0 - [Firebase/Database][I-RDB038012] Listener at /users/profile/FXovV1ZyKieaaTiIfaPv3O5gI383 failed: permission_denied`

Comment: @Jay if its a problem with accessing my firebase database, I updated my rules to this:
`{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
       "$uid": {
    ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
` and nothing has changed it is still giving me that message in the debugger

Comment: Yep - your user is not authenticated so you won't have read/write access. Set them back to default and see my answer.

Comment: Oh also, the error in your comment `/users/profile/FXovV1ZyKieaaTiIfaPv3O5gI383` is due to trying to read the */users* node, not the*/posts* node but either way, neither can be read by an unauthenticated user

Comment: You have two things going 1) a possible issue reading firebase and/or 2) a possible issue with your tableView. When coding, it's a good idea to focus on one issue at a time because if you are not reading any data from Firebase, you tableView will definitely not show any data. Let's get the firebase part working first, then we can worry about the tableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding this as a separate answer since my first answer addressed a possible issue reading from Firebase. Now there's an issue with the tableView.

The attached code is a complete and runnable project - soup to nuts, other than a PostTableViewCell xib which is literally a UITableViewCell subclass and matching xib - no other code.

I hope you can use this as a template to compare against your code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    class PostClass {
        var post_text = ""
    }

    var tableView:UITableView!

    var posts = [PostClass]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupTableView()

        //create two posts just to test the tableView
        let p0 = PostClass()
        p0.post_text = "Hello Row 0"
        let p1 = PostClass()
        p1.post_text = "And Row 1"
        self.posts.append(contentsOf: [p0, p1])
    }

    func setupTableView() {

        tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)

        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide!
        layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        let post = self.posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = post.post_text
        return cell
    }
}
```

and an image of the result

[image]

Comment: please take a look at my updated question, it shows how my TableView looks like with sample data also I show my `PostTableViewCell`, `Post` class, and `PostTableViewCell.xib` codes

Comment: also do you think it is my Firebase rules that are not allowing the posts to display? Do I need to create rules for "posts" and "users" to allow the data to display?

Comment: @allenhinson214 As we discussed above, according to what you said, your code to read firebase is working correctly as it output your firebase data to the console. That means you have something up with your tableView. If you were totally delete your code and use mine, following the design pattern, it will work for you as well. once you have something displaying, you can further refine that code to meet your needs.

Comment: Ok I will do that and let you know what happens, thank you for all the help and explanations that you have provided.

Comment: So I tried your code just like this and it displayed the two sample posts perfectly fine just like yours, but when I go to customize and add my code to grab the posts from my firebase database no data is still displayed. I'm still not sure why I am having this issue, could it be something with my firebase rules for not allowing a post to display on the viewtable? I have updated my question with the current rules I have now, it still prints the post in the console so the code to grab the data from firebase is working it is just not displaying it.

Comment: @allenhinson214 Right. The issue goes back to how you are modifying your tableView. There's something being omitted and not set up correctly. Again, I think you are putting the cart before the horse; you should be taking one component from Firebase, your post text for example, and displaying that in the tableview. In other words, Don't modify the tableView until you know you can display at least something from firebase. Once that's working, *then* modify the tableView and if it doesn't work, you know that Firebase *isn't* the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should change `postRef.observe(.value, with:` in your code to `postRef.observe(.childAdded, with:` , this way observe function will be called every time new child is added to posts reference.

Comment: I tried changing this and adding your suggested code and it is still not displaying the posts. I'm still stumped on this and not sure why it is doing this.

Comment: I doesn't show posts at all or doesn't show new posts?

Comment: `. value` listens for all types of changes to the data. So the code is okay here I think.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question as the problem is not about *how* the data from Firebase, it's either about *if* the data is read and possibly a tableView config issue. Also, if the function is changed to .childAdded, the code within the firebase closure would need to be changed as well. That being said, this is 100% a good suggestion to prevent the entire dataset being reloaded every time there's a change.

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are denying permission to read that node: they are set to the default which requires an authenticated user to read/write any data. You app needs to have authentication, so you would add something along these lines to the top of your main viewController

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class ViewController: UIViewController,
```

and then add in authentication code. You will need to have a User set up in your Firebase Console and call this function in viewDidLoad

```
func authUser() {
     Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: "users email", password: "password", completion: { (auth, error) in
        if let x = error { //example error checking
            let err = x as NSError
            switch err.code {
            case AuthErrorCode.wrongPassword.rawValue:
                print("wrong password")
            case AuthErrorCode.invalidEmail.rawValue:
                print("invalued email")
            default:
                print("unknown error")
            }
        } else { //no error, user is authed
            if let user = auth?.user {
                print("uid: \(user.uid)") //print their uid
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**OR**

for testing you can allow anyone read/write access by changing the rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

but that's very insecure so don't leave it that way.

**EDIT**

The other issue is in how your working with the read data from Firebase. The if statement will totally bail if anything is wrong - for example a specified child is not in one of the nodes being read.

To correct that evaluate each child separately and provide a default value in case the child is missing.

Assume a struture like this

```
posts
   post_0
      author
         uid: "uid_0"
         username: "uid 0 username"
      url: "www.someurl.com"
      post_text: "My post about posting"
```

and then the code to read all of the posts (and the child data) and output it to console.

```
func readPosts() {
    let postsRef = self.ref.child("posts") //self.ref points to my firebase
    postsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print("inside the observe closure")
        let allPosts = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for postSnap in allPosts {
            let authorSnap = postSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "author")
            let uid = authorSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "uid").value as? String ?? "NO UID!"
            let username = authorSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as? String ?? "NO USERNAME!"
            let postTitle = postSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "post_title").value as? String ?? "NO POST TITLE!"
            let url = postSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "url").value as? String ?? "NO URL!"
            print(uid, username, postTitle, url)
        }
    }, withCancel: { error in
        let err = error as NSError
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    })
}
```

and the output looks like this

```
uid_0 uid 0 username My post about posting www.someurl.com
uid_1 uid 1 username Things about posting www.anotherurl.com
```

Comment: So I followed you code that you suggested to put on my main vewcontroller which gives the options for people to sign in or sign up, both options are button that direct them to another viewcontroller. When I run the application with this code and the same firebase rules it still gives me that same permission_denied error. I went back to change the rules for everyone to read and write and when I ran the app, it didn't give me that error but it still doesn't show any data.

Comment: I changed my rules to this `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth !=null",
      ".write": "auth !=null"
  }
}
` and this seems to work as far not giving me a permission_denied statement in the debugger, but still not showing any data from Firebase

Comment: @allenhinson214 that's a start but are you authenticating your user per the code in my answer?

Comment: that is correct I am following the code that you included in your answer and that got rid of the permission_denied error in the debugger along side the database rules I displayed on my last comment.

Comment: @allenhinson214 good. Now, re-read the comments to the question where I suggested a way to ensure your tableView datasource is populated. Once you know you actually have data from Firebase stored in self.posts, you can do more troubleshooting. If that array is NOT populated then there's in issue with your Firebase code. If that array IS populated then the error is with your tableView. You've got to establish some baselines before moving forward.

Comment: I looked back at the other comments that you mentioned and tried them out. The first one I did was looked to see if the `self.posts` is being populated from Firebase and when I entered `self.posts.forEach { print($0) }` under the `self.posts = tempPosts ` and no data was shown (I'm assuming it would show the Firebase Data being populated in the debugger area). I then tried looking at my Table to see if it was an issue with that and used this code `cell.textLabel!.text = "Hello, World"` in place of `cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])` and nothing was shown.

Comment: like I said when I first created my table, I entered sample data that was placed in the `var posts = [Post] ()` as `var posts =  [ Post (id: "1", author: "Allen", text: "Hello World") ]` and this would populate correctly when I ran the app in my tableview.

Comment: @allenhinson214 Well, there you go. If you added a print statement to print out the data read from Firebase, and it prints nothing, that would indicate nothing was read from firebase. The way your working with the read data is really the issue - that `if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,` will fail is anything is wrong, which will mean your dataSource is never populated, but you won't know what specifically failed. I am updating my answer with a better way to do that.

Comment: I have entered the code you provided, as you can see in my updated question, and I am still not getting anything displayed. When it comes to looking at the outcome or if the data is being pulled from Firebase, I'm not sure where to find that. Would it show that in the debugger area or is there somewhere else in xcode I need to be looking at?

Comment: @allenhinson214 If you add print statements in your code, it will print to the bottom of the XCode window.

Comment: @allenhinson214 Also, your structure would have to match the one in my answer identically and you need to define self.ref to point to your firebase. Remember your question didnt include your structure so I had to guess.

Comment: @allenhinson214 I update the code in my answer with a print statement and an error handler. Try that. See if it prints "inside the observe closure" or an error.

Comment: My if you look at my original answer you can see that I am pointing it to my firebase: ` let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

        postRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in` unless this is not correct. I'm also confused to why you have Post Title when my database doesn't have that so I can't copy your code identically for it grab my data. I still don't see anything printing. Here is a screen shot of what pops up: https://ibb.co/nQr4sKg
https://ibb.co/LDKq531

Comment: @allenhinson214 If you look at that link in your comment, you can clearly see it has nothing to do with Firebase and is a problem with your UITableView. But again, you have not verified you are even reading any data from Firebase and if you don't have data, your tableView will not display anything. So start troubleshooting the Firebase aspect; print your data to console and once you are certain data is being read, you can then troubleshoot the tableView issue. Don't part the cart in front of the horse..

Comment: So I did some more looking around and found that my code is pulling data from my firebase. Under the `postsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in` I added `print(snapshot.value)` and it looks like my post data is being pulled from Firebase and displayed in the console as shown here: https://ibb.co/D1XmFfV Is it possible that I need to add a table view in my view controller via Swift UI instead of doing it programmatically?

Comment: @allenhinson214 Good, Now at least you can eliminate the Firebase code as being a the cause of the problem. From here, you could have a number of issues with your tableView. I don't know why you're adding it programmatically but it's often easier to build it in InterfaceBuilder in XCode. That being said, I took your code from the question, copy and pasted it into a fresh project, commented out the firebase calls, added in a PostClass and ran it, and it worked. The only other difference is my `PostTableViewCell` has no code other than the default, so your issue may be there.

Comment: @allenhinson214 Added a complete tableView example as an answer so you can compare it against your code. If any of this helps, please be sure to accept one of the answers so it can help others.