# Displaying a users data from Firebase in a tableview

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display a "post" on a tableview that I set up programmatically. When I go to run the application, the data that is stored in my database under the node "posts" is not being displayed. I've been trying to figure this out for a while and it really has me stumped. Here is the code below for ViewController that will be displaying the data.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeViewController:UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableView:UITableView!

    var posts = [Post] ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide

        layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.reloadData()

        observePosts()

    }

    func observePosts() {
        let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

        postsRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

            var tempPosts = [Post]()
            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                    let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                    let author = dict["author"] as? [String:Any],
                    let uid = author["uid"] as? String,
                    let username = author["username"] as? String,
                    let photoURL = author["photoURL"] as? String,
                    let url = URL(string:photoURL),
                    let text = dict["text"] as? String,
                let timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? Double {

                    let userProfile = UserProfile(uid: uid, fullname: username, photoURL: url)
                    let post = Post(id: childSnapshot.key, author: userProfile, text: text, timestamp: timestamp)
                    tempPosts.append(post)
                }
            }

            self.posts = tempPosts
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

Also my rules to firebase are shown below:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Before I tried loading data in my tableview from Firebase, I created mock data that went in the array at `var posts = [Post] ()` which took the place of "Post" inside that array and it displayed perfectly fine so I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: The Firebase portion of the code works for me. Note though, you're adding an .value observer to the posts node and any time *any* post is added, changed or removed ALL of the posts will reload. You may want to consider using a more granular approach with .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved or switch the .observe to .observeSingleEvent so it only fires once.

Comment: Have you verified you Firebase data is actually loading into self.posts?

Comment: Also, you seem to be posting [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59091483/displaying-a-users-post-on-xcode) from different accounts. That makes it really hard to help so please stick with one account and update your question with more details.

Comment: @Jay I'm not sure how to check whether or not firebase data is loading into self.posts, like I said I'm new to firebase and swift so I apologize for the inconvenience this may be. I've just been stuck trying to figure out this portion of my app. Do I need to change certain in rule in Firebase?

Comment: This is the reason to stick with ONE question. I explained how to do that on your other question - my last comment. Also, if your rules are set to default then you will need to authenticate before any data can be read or written.

Answer (score -1):

Your `UITableView` is not on the main thread.
Add this code to your `observePosts()`

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Ok so I added this to my code under the func observePosts( ) and it looks like this 
`self.posts = tempPosts
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData() ` but now instead of showing multiple tableview lines it shows a blank white screen with no data

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repository so I can take a look at it?

Comment: I do not have one, is there another of sharing the files with you?

Comment: Okay, you said that the UITableView cells are not showing up. Try to add print(posts.count) to your `observePosts` method. If the value == 0, the problem could be with your DB reference.

Comment: Where should this code be added? UI calls in Firebase closures are automatically run on the main thread.